# Converting an array of time increments to an array of instants

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

If I have an array of time increments, for example:

```
intervals = np.random.normal(loc=1,scale=0.1,size=100)
```

one possible way to create the corresponding array of time instants is to create a list and  manually make the sum:

```
Sum=0.
instants=[]
for k in range(len(intervals)):
    Sum+=intervals[k]
    instants.append(Sum)

instants=np.array(instants)
```

So, I have just switched from a array of `dt(i)` to an array of `t(i)`.

But usually python offers elegant alternatives to using `for` loops. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: It like a cummulative sum, so `np.cumsum(intervals)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you here describe is the cumulative sum. You can calculate this with [**`.cumsum()`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html):

```
intervals.cumsum()
```

For example:

```
>>> intervals
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> intervals.cumsum()
array([ 0,  1,  3,  6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45])
```